# Excel-vba Unzip password protected files and consolidated

Tags: excel, vba

I receive 50 compressed files (password protected) with ".zip" extension. Each file has a separate password. I have  to manually enter password for all the files and then merge them into one file before beginning my work. I am looking for some help around this. A macro that opens all files saved in a folder automatically by looping though the passwords I save somewhere in the sheet. Further once all files are opened, it merges them into one file.

Any help around this would be highly appreciated

Comment: Look into 7-zip. I believe it has a command-line version where you can specify the password.

Answer (score 0):

www​.rondebruin.nl/merge.htm download the addin. Hope it would work for u.